# R plotly add_annotations size parameter

Tags: r, plotly

With the R `plotly` package 4.5.2 I have been unable to get `add_annotations` to respect the `size` argument.  The following code produces annotations both of the same size:

```
require(plotly)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_markers(p,x=~1:2, y=~1:2)
p <- add_annotations(p, x=~c(1.1, 2.1), y=~c(1.2, 2.4),
                     text=~c('XXX','YYY'), size=~c(7,20))
p
```

Comment: This is not the way the docs recommend using multiple annotations. That being said, the example [here (see Multiple Annotations section)](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/undefined) doesn't work for me (also tried to mold your code to this way, with no success).

Comment: Correct, that doesn't work either, and with `plotly` 4.5.2 it's no longer the recommended approach.  Everything in my code works except for the `size` argument.

Comment: The example mentioned above now works (new github commit fixed it). Applying the same logic to your example (and using `add_annotations`), I still couldn't get the size working. The quest goes on.

Comment: I interpret that to mean that the github commit was only a partial fix, i.e. it fixed things for the older calling format only.

Comment: That is my impression as well. I'll post a new issue.

Comment: There has been new development at https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/745#issuecomment-251112608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem (in 2021). I was able to fix it with...

```
 p %>% add_annotations(
   x = your_x,
   y = your_y,
   text = your_text,
   font=list(size=8)#or whatever size you want
   )
```